# Jquery else does not work

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Cant' make this jquery work properly:

```
$(".btn-0").click(function(){
    $('.btn-0').addClass('btn-success');
    $('.btn-1,.btn-2, .btn-3, .btn-4, .btn-7, .btn-10, .btn-13, .btn-16, .btn-19, .btn-22, .btn-25, .btn-28, .btn-31, .btn-34, .btn-37, .btn-40, .btn-43, .btn-46, .btn-49, .btn-52').removeClass('btn-success');
});

if ($('.btn-0').hasClass('btn-success')) {
    $('.option-1').addClass('green'); 
}
else {
    $('.option-1').removeClass('green');
}
```

the idea is: if btn-0 has class btn-success, div option-1  receives class green...
if btn-1/btn-2/btn-3 has class btn-success, div option-2  receives class green...
etc..

the HTML is:

```
 <div class="option-1 row">
    <div class="col-md-1"><span class=" badge-0">#</span></div>
    <div class="atividade col-md-8"><p>Painel – O cenário econômico brasileiro <span class="red">(60 minutos)</span></p>Bradesco
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><a id="test" class="btn-0 btn btn-small btn-danger">9h30</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option-2 row" >
   <div class="col-md-1"><span class=" badge-1">1</span></div>
   <div class="col-md-8"><p>A sucessão no negócio Bob’s. Como preparar os herdeiros para o sucesso?</p>  Valéria Ribeiro </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"><a class="btn-1 btn btn-small btn-danger">9h30</a> <a class="btn-2 btn btn-small btn-danger">10h15</a> <a class="btn-3 btn btn-small btn-danger">11h</a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="option-3 row" >
   <div class="col-md-1"><span class=" badge-2">2</span></div>
   <div class="col-md-8"><p>Como identificar e negociar o ponto ideal </p>Sérgio Iunis</div>
   <div class="col-md-3"><a class="btn-4 btn btn-small btn-danger">9h30</a> <a class="btn-5 btn btn-small btn-danger">10h15</a> <a class="btn-6 btn btn-small btn-danger">11h</a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="option-4 row">
  <div class="col-md-1"><span class=" badge-3">3</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-8"><p>O futuro dos meios de pagamento no varejo </p> Mastercard</div> 
  <div class="col-md-3"><a class="btn-7 btn btn-small btn-danger">9h30</a> <a class="btn-8 btn btn-small btn-danger">10h15</a> <a class="btn-9 btn btn-small btn-danger">11h</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

anyone?

Comment: "else" is part of JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: if button has class `option-1` and you are checking `btn-success`

Comment: you are saying if it has class option-1 (but you are checking btn-success)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier if you made `$('.btn-1,.btn-2, .btn-3, .btn-4, .btn-7, .btn-10, .btn-13, .btn-16, .btn-19, .btn-22, .btn-25, .btn-28, .btn-31, .btn-34, .btn-37, .btn-40, .btn-43, .btn-46, .btn-49, .btn-52')` a little shorter by targeting one css class (add a class to all those buttons)

Comment: I think OP worded the question wrong since btn-success class is added/removed in the click handler. OP: when did you want this check to have its effect?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake, if button has class btn-success, div (option-1) content receives class green... else, class green must be removed!
You are right @Huangism, I made a mistake! I have a list of buttons and divs.... if button has class btn-success, the div button is receives class green!
if I click on another button, I need to remove class green from div!

Comment: Please be more detailed, which button are you referring to? Post simple html if you need to but so far your js has numerous button classes

Comment: You should add another event handler to the "other buttons" to remove the class green when clicked

Comment: @Huangism Just added more details! Thanks for you pacience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want but not 100% sure

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('.row');
    if( row.hasClass('btn-success') ) {
        row.removeClass('btn-success green');
    } else {
        row.addClass('btn-success green');
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pLdBU/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".btn-0").click(function(){
    $('.btn-0').addClass('btn-success');
    $('.btn-1,.btn-2, .btn-3, .btn-4, .btn-7, .btn-10, .btn-13, .btn-16, .btn-19, .btn-22, .btn-25, .btn-28, .btn-31, .btn-34, .btn-37, .btn-40, .btn-43, .btn-46, .btn-49, .btn-52').removeClass('btn-success');

if ($('.btn-0').hasClass('btn-success')) {
    $('.option-1').addClass('green'); 
}
else {
    $('.option-1').removeClass('green');
}
});
```

Comment: by looking at the logic in the click handler, I believe OP worded the question wrong

Comment: Thanks Clayton! I made a mistake!
the right question is: if button has class btn-success, div  (option-1) content receives class green... else, class green must be removed!

Comment: And you said it wasn't working correctly? Did you try adding it inside of the click handler? I made the edit above to show what it might look like.

Comment: @Clayton that can't be it since btn-0 will always have the success class when clicked. OP needs to provide more detail on how it 's supposed to behave

Comment: Yep! I tried like this before, but still not working! It adds the class to div but doesn't remove the class if .btn-0 doesn't have class btn-success

Comment: @user2142185 read my comment from the question (be more detailed, give examples) and update your question. Currently it is unclear how this thing should behave. At least provide the html so we know what we are dealing with

Comment: Are you trying to add and remove the class on click? If so you could just use the toggleClass() method. However, as @Huangism said, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish here.